# Silverlight application not communicating with web service on server

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis, asynchronous

I have developed a Silverlight application locally on my laptop.

Everything works fine however when I deploy it to the server the web service runs fine, in that it talks to the data base and gets the desired results. My problem lies with the front-end `SL` app where it is bringing up this error:

```
Debugging resource strings are unavailable

   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at FrontEnd.WebService.UIDReturnCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   at FrontEnd.Views.Users.client_UIDReturnCompleted(Object sender, UIDReturnCompletedEventArgs e)
   at FrontEnd.WebService.Service1SoapClient.OnUIDReturnCompleted(Object state)
Caused by: [Async_ExceptionOccurred]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.1.10329.0&File=System.dll&Key=Async_ExceptionOccurred
```

So I went to the link given and it stated that is was a `Async_ExceptionOccurred` error. 
Is this a timing issue? The `UIDReturn`is a web method that brings back a user ID from the database, this is initiated on page load of the Silverlight page, I thought perhaps the value was not back in time and therefore this is why it was crashing however this works locally and on the test server so perhaps it is an IIS issue?

Here is where the web service is called-

```
 void OnLoadCompleted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string fullUserName = WebContext.Current.User.DisplayName;
        string userName = fullUserName.Substring(fullUserName.IndexOf('\\') + 1);


        WebService.Service1SoapClient client = new WebService.Service1SoapClient();

            client.UIDReturnCompleted += new EventHandler<UIDReturnCompletedEventArgs>(client_UIDReturnCompleted);
            client.UIDReturnAsync(userName);

    }
```

The `fullUserName` is from the current logged in user, perhaps this value has not been loaded yet and due to this it is breaking the connection.

Comment: Can you post your code/Xaml? There are a number of reasons a real website will gives errors when first configured to run a Silverlight app that works fine locally (security settings etc)

Comment: Thanks for the input @HITech Magic, which code would you require? The call it makes on initialisation to the web service? Also would the crossdomain.xml perhaps be causing a conflict?

Comment: `crossdomain.xml` is just ignored if the other file is present. Start with supplying either the code for the call (if you are calling the service from code) or the XAML containing the data context (if you are using declarative data access).

Comment: @Jambo have you double checked that the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig has been updated with the right service URL or are you dynamically binding the endpoint of the web services ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to this post to which I have previously answered: [Consume WCF library in Silverlight 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229516/consume-wcf-library-in-silverlight-4-application/10231280#10231280)

Comment: I have the crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml files in both the web service directory in IIS and the wwwroot on the server. I can view them both by going to - http://localhost:10/crossdomain.xml and http://localhost:10/clientaccesspolicy.xml

Comment: @Jambo: You only need the more modern `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file with Silverlight if you are hosting your own site. `crossdomain.xml` will not be used if the other file exists *and is only there for compatibility with existing Flash websites that use that file*.